# How to check if the web browser contains a specific string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, extjs5

I want to know how to check the web browser to see if a specific string of text exists.

For example, I want to validate that the string "Hello World" is visible on the browser. Any tips would be great. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried?  Where is this string supposed to be?  On the webpage?  In the URI?  In a bookmark?  Do you mean `visible` as in it's current CSS allows it to be physically seen on the screen?

Comment: can you try $(document).text().contains('Hello World') ?

Comment: This needs to work for IE. @Sushil, that doesn't work for IE.

Comment: @Sushil that's not what the OP is asking for, and your code is also wrong: there's no such thing as `.contains` for strings in Javascript.

Comment: @ScottKaye I just want to verify that a "sfldjsdjfk" is visible anywhere on the browser.

Comment: Does `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML.indexOf('Hello World')` accomplish what you want??

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles, not that does not.

Comment: You're going to have to be a lot more clear with what you're asking - @bloodyKnuckles's solution will return the location (index) of "Hello World" if it exists anywhere in the HTML of the page, or `-1` if it isn't found.

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles You could also grab the body quicker with `document.body`

Comment: @MarcoBonelli the code i've given is in jquery and it does have a .contains property. you can just open your console window in chrome for this very page and run the code. it will work.

Comment: @VKid I've tried this in IE 11. which version are you running?

Comment: @Sushil console says object don't support property or method 'contain' using IE11

Comment: are you trying 'contain' or contains? which version of jquery are you running? can you share what you're trying?

Comment: both. contain and contains

Comment: can you share your code? it is difficult for us to assume what you're writing.

Comment: @Sushil the [jQuery `.text()` method](https://api.jquery.com/text/) returns a **string**, and strings do not have a `.contains()` method. Check the documentation and run it on your console before claiming that it's correct, because it's not.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli. I ran it in my console before posting it.

Comment: @Sushil That's just impossible dude. Create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and link it to me, I'm really courious.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli you can see this link. i've just taken a screenshot http://postimg.org/image/wepviivyd/

Comment: @Sushil Yeah, that'a because Stack Overflow has another library which adds the `.contains` method to the `String.prototype`, but try running it on another site (e.g. Google), and you'll see that it's wrong.

Comment: oh @MarcoBonelli. then I maybe wrong. I just tried it on this site. thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick for you...

```
if($('html:contains("Hello World")').length > 0){
   alert('Hello World! I exist!');
}else{
   alert('Goodbye cruel world!')
}
```

Comment: thank you. exactly what i was looking for. @Ted , is there a way to have it not return those alert?

Comment: just remove the alert lines and put whatever code you need in there